# @Ajax.ActionLink redirects to previous page instead to send data to controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

I have @Ajax.ActionLink call by which I am trying to pass data to controller and refresh partial view. When I click on the link instead of passing the data to the controller, it is redirecting me to the previous page.

Ajax code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(@mainType.Descr, "GetChosenFaqSubCategory", "FAQ",
          new { @TabCode = @mainType.TabCode },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              UpdateTargetId = "reloadFaq",
              HttpMethod = "POST",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
          })
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetChosenFaqSubCategory(string TapCode)
    {
        string pFilter = "WebFaqCategoryCd=" + TapCode;

        code...

        return PartialView("GlobalFAQ", List);
    }
```

As bundles I am loading:

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryunobtr").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ajax").Include(
               "~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax*",
               "~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax*"));
```

In the Web.config unobtrusive is allowed:

```
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(@mainType.Descr, "GetChosenFaqSubCategory", "FAQ",
          new { @TabCode = @mainType.TabCode },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              UpdateTargetId = "reloadFaq",
              HttpMethod = "POST",
              InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
          })
```

You have @TabCode here but it would try to look for @TabCode in your parameters. Try it with "TabCode = @mainType.TabCode"

For better readability it looks like you're using an int to identify the Tab that is selected. TabId would probably be better when looking at it without documentation.